# Return tasks not performed

Tags: mysql

I have this query that returns the tasks that were performed each day:

```
SELECT B.gen_date, tarefa
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT A.gen_date
        FROM
            (
                select * 
                from 
                    (
                        select 
                            adddate('2019-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) gen_date 
                        from
                            (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
                            (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
                            (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
                            (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
                            (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4
                    ) v
                where gen_date between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31'

                UNION ALL

                SELECT DATE_FORMAT(IniciarTarefa, '%Y-%m-%d')
                FROM raddb.Tarefa
            ) AS A
    ) AS B 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.Tarefa 
        ON DATE_FORMAT(raddb.Tarefa.IniciarTarefa, '%Y-%m-%d') = B.gen_date
WHERE B.gen_date between '2019-06-01' AND '2019-06-10'
GROUP BY tarefa, B.gen_date, DATE_FORMAT(IniciarTarefa, '%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER BY gen_date
```

That returns a result like this:

[image]

I have 3 types of tasks (1, 2 and 3). 
For example on day 1 it returns that only task 2 was performed, day 2 returns task 1 and day 3 was performed all tasks. 
Then he wanted it to return that on day 1, task 1 and 3 was not executed, day 2 and 3 were not performed and day 3 did not return anything, since all tasks were performed. I show example in the image what I want it to return:

[image]

Comment: Did you write this code? It looks like you copied pieces from others and put together and you don't have any clue what it does :)

Comment: @krish KM Yes, I copied the part of the code that generates the days of the year, I know what the code does. I still have not been able to perceive in what way I arrive at what I intend.